# How to use both dashed-negatives defalut style + line colors in Matplotlib/Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, contour

When drawing a contour plot with Python/Matplotlib, the default behaviour (for 1 color) is that negative values are dashed. This is a desired feature for me. However, if I set the color of the lines, all of them are drawn solid. I would like to combine the dashed negatives and custom colors.

**How can I plot colored lines, and keep the negative-dahsed style?**

Below, I copy (modifying a bit), an example from this tutorial: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-data-science/9781491912126/ch04.html

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)
Z = f(X, Y)

# Default: 1 color, negatives are dashed
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='black')
plt.show()

# Set colormap: all lines are solid
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdBu')
plt.show()

# Set individual colors: all solid lines
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors=['b','b','b','r','r','r','r','r'])
plt.show()
```

Defalut: negatives are dashed.
[image: Default]

Set colors via colormap: all have become solid.
[image: Colormap]

Set individual colors: all solid again. I would like the blue lines here to be dashed, automatically, since they are negative values.
[image: Individual lines with colors]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the feature of different linestyles for negative values is not exposed to the user. It is bound to whether or not a single color is used for the lines. This toggles a property `monochrome`, which in turn decides whether or not to change the linestyle.

A quick hack is hence to set the `monochrome` attribute to True and reset the linesstyles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)
Z = f(X, Y)


cntr = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdBu')
cntr.monochrome = True
for col, ls in zip(cntr.collections, cntr._process_linestyles()):
    col.set_linestyle(ls)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Since this uses a private `._process_linestyles()` attribute, it would not be recommended to use it in production code; but rather use [@WarrenWeckesser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005617/4124317) or the option below.

Here I would like to point to the option to set the `linestyles` a priori, depending on the levels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)
Z = f(X, Y)


loc = matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator(7)
lvls = loc.tick_values(Z.min(), Z.max())
cntr = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=lvls, cmap='RdBu', 
                   linestyles=np.where(lvls >= 0, "-", "--"))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you can do it.  (A matplotlib guru might be able to recommend an easier way.)

This example uses a colormap to set the colors, and then changes the linestyles after the contour plot is created.  A dashed line is used for negative contours, a dotted line for 0, and a solid line for positive.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 40)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)
Z = f(X, Y)

# Contour with a specified colormap.
result = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdBu')

# Override the linestyles based on the levels.
for line, lvl in zip(result.collections, result.levels):
    if lvl < 0:
        line.set_linestyle('--')
    elif lvl == 0:
        line.set_linestyle(':')
    else:
        # Optional; this is the default.
        line.set_linestyle('-')

# Optional--this makes the 0 contour more visible with the
# chosen colormap.
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('#d0d0d0')

plt.show()
```

Here's the result:

[image: plot]

Comment: There isn't really any easier way, unfortunately. So this is definitely a good option to use.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. I accepted the next answer, because it added an explanation for why this happens.